# Terraform variable validation when calling a module

Tags: terraform

I have a module that accepts a variable with a validation as follows

```
variable "policy_statements" {
  description = "The statements of the policies to be created"
  type = map(object({
    path         = string
    capabilities = set(string)
  }))

  validation {
    condition     = contains(["create", "read", "update", "patch", "delete", "list"], var.policy_statements.capabilities)
    error_message = "Valid values for capabilities are (\"create\", \"read\", \"update\", \"patch\", \"delete\", \"list\")."
  }
}
```

I am then calling this module from another tf module:

```
module "policies" {
  source = "../../../../path/to"

  for_each = var.policies

  policy_statements = each.value

}
```

In the outer module, the `policies` variable is declared as

```
variable "policies" {
  description = "The statements of the policies to be created"
  type           = map(any)
}
```

Invocation fails with:

```
│   on ../../../../path/to/variables.tf line 13, in variable "policy_statements":
│   13:     condition     = contains(["create", "read", "update", "patch", "delete", "list"], var.policy_statements.capabilities)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.policy_statements is map of object with 2 elements
│
│ This map does not have an element with the key "capabilities".
```

The outer module reads the `policies` variable in a `terragrunt.hcl` as below:

```
locals {
  policies = yamldecode(file("config.yaml"))
}

inputs = {
  policies = local.policies
}
```

where `config.yaml`

```yaml
policies:
  policy-test-1:
    capabilities:
      - read
      - create
    path: /foo/lala
  policy-test-2:
    capabilities:
      - update
      - delete
    path: /foo/lala
```

What is the reason of the validation failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message notes, `var.policy_statements` is a *map of objects*, not just a single object. In your example data, the keys of that map are `policy-test-1` and `policy-test-2`, so it's correct that there is no map key named "capabilities".

I think you are intending to check that condition for each element of the map, to verify that *all* of the objects meet the condition. If so, you can use a `for` expression in conjunction with the `alltrue` function to generate a list of condition results for each element in the map and then fail if any of them are `false`:

```
  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for stmt in var.policy_statements :
      contains(["create", "read", "update", "patch", "delete", "list"], stmt.capabilities)
    ])
    error_message = "Valid values for capabilities are (\"create\", \"read\", \"update\", \"patch\", \"delete\", \"list\")."
  }
```

Notice that in this example the `capabilities` attribute is checked for each `stmt` object and therefore each object in the map, rather than treating `capabilities` as a key for the map itself.